# What is the usage of isTraversableAgain function in GenTraversableLike

Tags: scala

isTraversableAgain is declared final in [GenTraversableLike](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_1_final/src//library/scala/collection/GenTraversableLike.scala#L64) and with its plethora of [Known Subclasses](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/GenTraversableLike.html), I would like to know the usage of the function and the wisdom behind its being final.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That method is defined on `GenTraversableOnce`, which is kind of a father to everything. Among that everything is `Iterator`, which can only be traversed once, and everything else, which is expected to be traversable multiple times. Though, of course, you can go up to `GenTraversableOnce` or `TraversableOnce` and subclass it with something else that is only traversable once.

The methods declared on `GenTraversableLike` rely on being able to traverse a collection multiple times.

Comment: ah... I trace isTraversableAgain from List and get to GenTraversableLike through linearization and miss the original source GenTraversableOnce. Thanks Daniel.

Comment: The fact that it is a method implies that you might want to call it at runtime and make a decision about how to handle the collection based on the result. I'm having trouble imagining what situation that would be though I guess it is not impossible.

Comment: @Owen `grep`? The method `toArray` uses it to decide whether to copy the whole collection to an intermediate collection first (if false), or call size to initialize the array and then copy the collection.